# How to Change string/label field dynamically in tree view odoo?

Tags: view, tree, label, odoo

I would like to change colonne's label or string when change boolean value:

This solution didn't work:

```
<field name="product_uom_qty" attrs="{'invisible':[('x_is_line_commission','==', True)]}" string="Ordered Qty" context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom, 'company_id': parent.company_id}" />

<field name="product_uom_qty" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_is_line_commission','!=', True)]}" string="Ordered Value" context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom, 'company_id': parent.company_id}" />
```

And this solution it work only for form view but didn't work with tree view

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-to-create-dynamic-field-labels-20501

And i didn't  know if this solution work or not :

https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/186683

Thx for support

Answer (score 0):

You have used `==` operator in condition which is wrong. It will work with `=` operator. Value of boolean field can be *True* or *False*

Try with this:

Replace

```
<field name="product_uom_qty" attrs="{'invisible':[('x_is_line_commission','==', True)]}" string="Ordered Qty" context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom, 'company_id': parent.company_id}" />
```

with

```
<field name="product_uom_qty" attrs="{'invisible':[('x_is_line_commission','=', True)]}" string="Ordered Qty" context="{'partner_id':parent.partner_id, 'quantity':product_uom_qty, 'pricelist':parent.pricelist_id, 'uom':product_uom, 'company_id': parent.company_id}" />
```

Comment: in odoo 9  both of them work (=) or (==) i tested it, but nothing . unfortunately at this moment odoo didn't change label of header tree view dynamically . thx @Odera